# Error says value moved in previous in iteration of loop, but this doesn't seem true

Tags: rust, move-semantics

As seen in the code below, each iteration of the loop defines its own instance of `Foo`, so I don't see how it could be "moved" in a "previous iteration of loop" when there is a new `Foo` per loop.

How do I make the error go away?

```rust
fn main() {
    for i in 0..2 {
        let vector: Foo;
        //  ------ move occurs because `vector` has type `Foo`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
        if i == 0 {
            vector = Foo::Bar(vec![1_f32]);
        } else if i == 1 {
            vector = Foo::Baz(vec![1_u16]);
        }
    //  - value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
        println!("{}", vector.len());
        //             ^^^^^^ value used here after move
    }
}

enum Foo {
    Bar(Vec<f32>),
    Baz(Vec<u16>)
}

impl Foo {
    pub fn len(self) -> usize {
        match self {
            Foo::Bar(vector) => vector.len(),
            Foo::Baz(vector) => vector.len(),
            #[allow(unreachable_patterns)]
            _ => unreachable!()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's really fixing the problem you want to fix, but a `len` shouldn't require a move, it should take `&self` instead.

Comment: That seams to be known bug with incorrect error message, by the way - https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/72649

Comment: Thank you for noticing this behaviour. I looked into it, and it was indeed a bug with the compiler diagnostics. I ended up writing a patch to fix it: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/87998. The pull request was merged into master today, so the fix should appear in the next release of the Rust compiler. The fixed compiler properly indicates that `vector` may be uninitialized on the `println!` line, rather than spuriously blaming the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if-else chain is not exhaustive:

```
fn main() {
    for i in 0..2 {
        let vector: Foo;
        if i == 0 {
            vector = Foo::Bar(vec![1_f32]);
        } else if i == 1 {
            vector = Foo::Baz(vec![1_u16]);
        }

        // What should happen if `i` is not 0 or 1 ?
        // Then the app will try to use an uninitialized variable
        // The compiler cannot figure out that it is impossible 
        // with the current input  
        println!("{}", vector.len());
    }
}
```

So you have to add an `else` statement for the case when `i` is not `0` or `1`:

```
fn main() {
    for i in 0..2 {
        let vector: Foo;
        if i == 0 {
            vector = Foo::Bar(vec![1_f32]);
        } else if i == 1 {
            vector = Foo::Baz(vec![1_u16]);
        } else {
            unreachable!();
        }

        println!("{}", vector.len());
    }
}
```

Or better use a `match` statement (as in your own answer) because it's much cleaner and easier to read:

```
fn main() {
    for i in 0..2 {
        let vector: Foo = match i {
            0 => Foo::Bar(vec![1_f32]),
            1 => Foo::Baz(vec![1_u16]),
            _ => unreachable!() 
        };
        println!("{}", vector.len());
    }
}
```

Relevant issue (thanks @nneonneo): https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/72649

Comment: The error message is extremely misleading then.  It has nothing to do with moving and everything to do with an unhandled case.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I think this warrants a bug report, actually. They've previously fixed such issues before: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/953104e60cac57929846a3c3b776f12135c4b398

Comment: looks similar to https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/72649, actually, which isn't fixed yet.

Comment: I'll add that issue to the answer, because not everyone reads thr comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By using a `match` statement I managed to make the errors go away.  I don't know why this works and the previous code didn't:

```rust
fn main() {
    for i in 0..2 {
        let vector: Foo = match i {
            0 => Foo::Bar(vec![1_f32]),
            1 => Foo::Baz(vec![1_u16]),
            _ => unreachable!()
        };
        println!("{}", vector.len());
    }
}
```